# How to disassemble an Acer Aspire 5730

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire, documentation, laptop-repair

I have an Acer Aspire 5730-4163 whose power jack has died. I'm looking for a disassembly how-to or service manual, preferably with clear pictures. Google hasn't turned up anything for me.

Anyone know of a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://www.laptopguides.info/acer/acer-aspire-5730z-service-manual/

Comment: Looks like the right one.

Comment: Dead link as of 2020/05/01